# WebStorm not recognising some Angular components - mat-toolbar unknown element

Tags: javascript, angular, webstorm, angular-material2

I am using Angular 5 with [Angular material](https://material.angular.io/) and WebStorm version 2017.3.1

When I try to use the `<mat-toolbar>` element with the following code

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.component.html*

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <span>Title</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

WebStorm gives me an error:

```
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

[image]

*However*, this renders correctly in the browser:

[image]

Because it *is* included in the module with this line `import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';` and

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,

  MatToolbarModule
],
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Why does WebStorm (and also when running tests via `ng test`) give me this error? How can I prevent this error/warning?

Comment: It feels like you'd have to restart your ng serve, this happens to me sometimes as well, like if the module import was ignored. Not related to webstorm tho.

Comment: @MattLishman Javascript and Webstorm are _both_ reasonable tags for this since you are working with both. Have you restarted your IDE since your  most recent `npm install ...` (close window explorers too)? That might fix the error showing in Webstorm, by clearing cache. For `ng test` you'd have to configure your spec file correctly. If your app runs flawless with `ng serve` then I'd suggest trying to ignore it since it's not a big issue.

Comment: @Z.Bagley Good suggestion about an IDE restart. This makes the error go away (even closing the project and reopening it does). This isn't an ideal solution though, so i'll submit a bug/feature request to JetBrains at some point to try do this automatically.
Feel free to add this as an answer and i'll accept if you think it's worth it.

Comment: this is not a webstorm error, message clearly comes from Angular service. Likely it's https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14961

Comment: @MattLishman Your answer works best for clearing this up and possibly helping others down the line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is generated via TypeScript.

You can see the error in the console if you click on the TypeScript tab at the bottom.

[image]

It's possible to make this error go away if you force the TypeScript service to restart by clicking on the arrow in a circle.

[image]

**This requires a compile first**.

So far, I cannot find a way to map this to a shortcut.

Thanks to @lena and @Z.Bagley for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Have you tried configuring TypeScript in Webstorm to Recompile On Changes?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from [Angular language service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/language-service).
Looks related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14961; see if updating Typescript to 2.5.2+ helps

Comment: This has nothing to do with `@angular/language-service` as that thread is specific to. This is a `@angular/material` issue with use with `Webstorm`. He's not receiving a compiler error, he's receiving a Webstorm IDE error.

Comment: Updating Typescript didn't make a difference. However, restarting the Typescript service via Webstorm caused the issue to go away (and come back correctly when I remove the module dependency).
I would argue this is related to Webstorm, they should restart the service when it is required (or do whatever is necessary to make the error go away in TS)

Comment: Thanks @lena, this helped me find a solution for now.

Comment: @Z. Bagley this issue is specific neither to @angular/material nor Webstorm - you will face it with any IDE that integrates with angular language service, and with any component. If you don't understand what you are commenting on, it's not a good reason for downvoting the answers

Comment: @Matt Lishman no, Webstorm shouldn't restart the service now and then to overcome Angular/Typescript bugs

Comment: Actually, I downvoted the answer. This was a suggestion that didn't work. 
It helped me to go and find that Typescript was responsible (changing the version forced Webstorm to pop open the tab, which caused me to notice the error), but it had nothing to do with upgrading the version.

Comment: @lena 'Issue' referred to the **github issue** that you posted which is very much specific only to language-service as I mentioned. Giving it's likely he's not using language-service in this project (from the code he's posted, very unlikely he's using it) this is an unrelated answer. As a side note, I typically don't downvote answers and didn't downvote yours, but am OK w/making an exception ;)

Comment: he is clearly using the service - it's enabled by default for angular apps in Webstorm, and the error message format is the angular one - WebStorm itself uses different format.

Comment: to make things clear: this service is not smth one would use directly in his code. This service was designed to integrate with IDEs and provide error checking within Angular Templates. see http://angularjs.blogspot.ru/2016/12/angular-230-now-available.html. It can be turned on/off in webstorm preferences, *Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript*, *Angular language service* checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the problem the OP had, but wanted to share this in case someone comes across this post and is still experiencing this problem in WebStorm and are **not** getting TypeScript compile errors, here's what worked for me: In WebStorm select menu item File > Invalidate Caches / Restart. This problem happened to me in WebStorm 2019.3 .